# Why i get undfined when i am using keyup event?

Tags: jquery, undefined, keypress

I want to alert the key that the user is pressed, so I used this jQuery keyup event handler:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $(".moveup").keyup(function() {
    alert(e.keyCode)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="moveup" type="text" placeholder="Press key for Up move" id="textset" name="upmove" />
```

All keys that I press I get "undefined".
I am using chrome browser.
what can be the problem?

Comment: You should use the event from keyup, not from ready.

Comment: `e` is the event object from the dom.ready handler not from your `keyup` handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e.keycode is undefined add the e to your keyup function

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( ".moveup" ).keyup(function(e) {
    alert(e.keyCode)
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for my typo keycode is undefined in e in his code.

Comment: I got it. I fixed it and now i am trying to insert my result to the same input , and for some reason i get my result twice. i used $(this).val(e.keyCode.toUpperCase) , and for every key that i set for new value i get double result. So for example i press "A" i am getting Aa . what can be the problem?

Comment: Can you place the js function wiuth the changes? I can have a better look then

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){


$( ".moveup" ).keypress(function(e) {
   $(this).val(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
  });
});` when i alert my "String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)" i get corret output, but when i check my input field i see double result like "ee","ff" ..

Comment: its happens only when i am trying to insert  the e.keyCode to the same input, so how can i handle this issue?

Comment: Im doing some test now, but why you whant to change the input fields value to the same key they pressed by using keycodes?